# Wrapping boost accumulators

Tags: c++, boost

Here is a namespace for wrapping boost accumulators for use in a broader code base. I love these accumulators but re-`typedef`ing them everywhere is ugly and a pain.

I am not interested in C++11 alternatives. My code base does not put the starting bracket on a new line. My code base uses doxygen. Most of the style choices are deliberate.

I'm interested in any issues with using this in a broader code base. If anyone has tips on doxygen style for this type of thing, that would be helpful too.

```
#ifndef ACCUMULATORS
#define ACCUMULATORS

#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/max.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/min.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>

//! The Accumulators namespace provides min, max, and average accumulators to the broader code base.
/*!
    This namespace defines accumulator types from boost. Also provided are specific extactors
    that will return the accumulator's current value.
*/
namespace Accumulators{

    //typedefs
    typedef boost::accumulators::accumulator_set< double,
        boost::accumulators::stats< boost::accumulators::tag::min>  > MinAccumulator;

    typedef boost::accumulators::accumulator_set< double,
        boost::accumulators::stats< boost::accumulators::tag::max>  > MaxAccumulator;

    typedef boost::accumulators::accumulator_set< double,
        boost::accumulators::stats< boost::accumulators::tag::mean> > MeanAccumulator;

    //extractors
    inline double extractMin(const MinAccumulator &acc){
        return  boost::accumulators::min(acc);
    }

    inline double extractMax(const MaxAccumulator &acc){
        return  boost::accumulators::max(acc);
    }

    inline double extractMean(const MeanAccumulator &acc){
        return  boost::accumulators::mean(acc);
    }
};
#endif
```

I would use this in another locations by including.

```
#include <Accumulators.h>
```

Then creating a one.

```
Accumulators::MaxAccumulator myMax;
```

Adding values

```
myMax(42); //... this is defined by boost
```

And then extracting the value for some other use.

```
Accumulators::extractMax(myMax);
```

Any issues with this or improvements that you can come up with?